# Phenom x6 overheating: temperature montiors show constant 0 degrees C

Tags: windows-7, temperature, amd-phenom

I have an AMD Phenom II x6 processor which is overheating very easily, especially considering it's water cooled.  I'm trying to monitor the temperature (in Windows 7) to see what's going on, but I can't seem to get a good reading on the core temperature.

I've tried two different programs: [HWMonitor](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html) and : [Core Temp](http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/)

Both of them just give readings of 0 degrees C for all the cores (obviously an error).

So I'm curious:

- What could be causing these programs to not measure the
  temperature?
- Is there any program that *could* monitor the temperature?
- Could this lack of temperature reading be associated with my
  computer overheating?
- If so, how could I remedy it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Core Temp's Support FAQ](http://www.alcpu.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=62&t=892) has this to say:

> **Why does my AMD processor's temperature always read 0C/32F?**
>
> ...On CPUs starting with the Phenom architecture AMD has introduced the ACC function, it allowed the early Phenoms to achieve higher overclocks, and on the Phenom II based processors it allowed unlocking of extra cores and L3 cache.
>
> Some motherboards include a Core unlock feature, which is based on ACC as well.
>   In most cases disabling these features in the BIOS will bring temperature readings back.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Turning Core unlock off fixed *all* of my problems!